# How to display curl http return status in jenkinsfile

Tags: curl, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My requirement is to display the HTTP return status in the jenkinsfile. In the Jenkinsjob console, the curl command is printing the HTTP output code but I am not able to capture it in a variable to be used later in a straightforward way.

Tried and working approach: Capture the curl output in a file and then filter it to capture the output code outside the "withCredentials" block, under the if-else block.

The jenkinsfile is as below-

```
pipeline {
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3', artifactNumToKeepStr: '3'))
    }

    agent any
    
    stages{
        stage('display status'){
            steps{
                    script{
                            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'deployer', passwordVariable: 'PW', usernameVariable: 'USER')]){
                            status = sh(
                            returnStatus: true,
                            script: """
                            set +x
                            **#NEED HELP HERE. WANT TO CAPTURE THE RETURN STATUS DIRECTLY IN A VARIABLE INSTEAD OF SAVING THE OUTPUT IN A FILE AND THEN FILTER IT**
                            curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"  "www.example.com"
                            set -x
                            """
                            )
                            if (status == 0) {
                               ***want to display status here returned by /curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n"  "www.example.com"/***
                               echo "success"
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "fail"
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that --write-out %{http_code} will return the code that can be saved to a variable.